# Processing- What could be possible errors of svg file not displayed?

Tags: svg, processing

I'm trying to display an svg image with Processing, but it would only show a blank white space. I don't think there is any problem with the code as it works perfectly when I change the `shape` to `ellipse`. Do I have to modify any code below to display the svg file, or is there any other possible reasons why it wouldn't show? Thanks in advance!

```
Table table;
PFont f;
PShape leaf;
color [] c = {color(225, 50, 50), color(225, 100, 0), color(225, 225, 0), color(0, 150, 0), color(0), color(125)};
int i=0;

void setup() {
  size(1100, 500);
  background(255);
  table=loadTable("P3_data.csv", "header");
  leaf= loadShape("leaf.svg");
  leaf.disableStyle();
}


void draw() {
  stroke(255);
  strokeWeight(0.1);

  for (TableRow row : table.rows()) {
    int friend= (row.getInt("Friend"));
    int travel= (row.getInt("Travel"));
    int selfimprovement= (row.getInt("Self-improvement"));
    int club= (row.getInt("Club"));
    int schoolwork= (row.getInt("Schoolwork"));
    int money= (row.getInt("Money"));

    int total= 0;
    int [] Daily= {friend, travel, selfimprovement, club, schoolwork, money};
    for (int k=0; k<6; k++) {
      total +=Daily[k];
    }
    println (total);
      for (int j=0; j<6; j++) {

      for (int m=0; m< Daily[j]; m++) {
      fill(c[j]);
        ellipse((i%120)*10+10, (i/120)*40+10, 3*total, 4*total);
       //shape(leaf, (i%120)*10+10, (i/120)*40+10, 3*total, 3*total);
        total --;
      }
    }
    if (i>1095) {
      break;
    }
    i++;
  }
  save("sketch.png");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation of [`disableStyle()`](https://processing.org/examples/disablestyle.html)

> Shapes are loaded with style information that tells them how to draw (the color, stroke weight, etc.) The `disableStyle()` method of `PShape` turns off this information. The `enableStyle()` method turns it back on.

If you want to display the *SVG* with its style, the you have to remove the `disableStyle` call:

`leaf = loadShape("leaf.svg");`
<s>`leaf.disableStyle();`</s>

---

If you want to change the stroke and fill color of the shape generated form the *svg" file, then indeed you have to disable the style:

```
leaf= loadShape("leaf.svg");
leaf.disableStyle();
```

In this case the shape is drawn with the current fill and stroke color. This means that all the shape is filled with the same fill color and drawn with the same stroke color:

```
 for (int m=0; m< Daily[j]; m++) {
     stroke(0, 0, 255); // blue
     fill(255, 0, 0); // red
     shape(leaf, (i%120)*10+10, (i/120)*40+10, 3*total, 3*total);
     total --;
 }
```

Comment: I'm trying to fill the shape with a different color from the original svg file, (different colors in every shape to be exact). I saw the tutorial when writing the code, and it doesn't say I need to use enableStyle(). I modified the code after reading your answer, but it still doesn't work.. Where should I insert the method?